# Appcelerator module cannot be found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have created a new Appcelerator project as I'm updating an old Appcelerator to a new one.

I'm having trouble with it recognising a module though. The module is:

`var map = require('bencoding.map');`

And it's included in the '/modules/iphone/bencoding.map/' folder.

I did include the module in the tiapp.xml file: `<module platform="iphone">bencoding.map</module>`

Anyone got any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears `bencoding.map` hasn't been updated in 4 years! It probably is no longer supported.

However, the build in `ti.map` has polygon support just like `bencoding.map` tried 4 years ago. Just look at the doc here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map

`ti.map` is included in the SDK. But should you need a download (to pin a version/include it in repo) just download it from their [Git repo](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/releases)